# undefined error en hacer peticion post de un json via jquey

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo el siguiente código donde quiero mandar un JSON vía API, pero cuando ejecuto el código falla y el fail devueleve undefined.

El mismo JSON si lo ejecuto en aplicaciones de API rest funciona.

```
            var order = [{
                id: '999',
                product: '2880',
                state: 'open',
                deliverydate: '1999/01/24',
                closingdate: '1999/01/24',
                user: 'doe@mail.net'
            }];
            
            alert(JSON.stringify(order));
            $.ajax({
                url: "localhost:8080/order",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({order}),
                success: function (data) { alert("succes:"+data); },
                error: function (errMsg) {
                    alert("error"+errMsg);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el mensaje de error que te da? Así podremos ser mas precisos con la respuesta.

Comment: me dice que el error es undefined